Anaconda create environment with a specific version of Python
I am trying to create an environment with Python 3.7, except when I run
conda create -n py37 python=3.7

in a terminal, I instead get
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.7*

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r

I checked my Anaconda distribution with
conda search python

and it only goes as far down as 3.8.11 (highest is 3.13.1). Is there any way to use Python 3.7?
I found [this package on Anaconda] (https://anaconda.org/OpenEye/OpenEye-toolkits-python3.7-win64) which I thought would give me Python 3.7, except running the pip install doesn't put Python 3.7 in the Anaconda environment, and running step 1 in the description
conda create -n oepython -c openeye openeye-toolkits

doesn't either.

What OS are you running?

Possibly related: Cannot install Python 3.7 on osx-arm64?

Thanks for drawing my attention to that post! I used conda config --env --set subdir osx-64 before conda create -n py37 python=3.7, and it works!

Perhaps a python 3.7 docker container might be an option

This question is similar to: Cannot install Python 3.7 on osx-arm64. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
